# How to do performance testing of an android application using jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter

What all the needed settings changes in my mobile for `jmeter` to capture the actions? I modified the WiFi settings, added my system's IP and port 8080. But when I tried to login to the application its showing `Service Unavailable`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check your configuration. Make sure that cellular data is turned off, JMeter's proxy is up and running and your Android device is configured to use host, running JMeter as proxy.
2. If your application uses HTTPS transport you may have to use external tool like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) to configure proxy settings on your mobile application.
3. Other HTTPS-related tip: when you start JMeter's proxy `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` self-signed certificate is being generated in JMeter's working folder (usually /bin). You need to install this certificate on your Android device, the easiest way is to send it to the device by email.
4. If above doesn't help - consider using free [Mobile Recorder](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1946705-mobile-recorder) service - in that case you won't have to worry about proxies, certificates, etc.